# What are the negative effects of setting a value to what it already is?

Tags: c#

I am hoping to get information on the negative computational effect of setting specific objects to a state regardless of what the current value is compared to checking and updating only if it is different.

One instance is of this would be as follows:

```
public void StopWatchBtn_Click(...)
{
    stopwatch.Start();
}

public void StopWatchBtnWithCheck_Click(...)
{
    if ( !stopwatch.isRunning )
        stopwatch.Start();
}
```

Alternatively, something that may have more consequence would be to set the text of a text box or attaching an object to a Tag that is the same as the string ( or Tag) that is being replaced. What I am thinking is that the negative computational cost associated with all the subsequent calls to update the textbox (or tag) would be longer than the computational cost of just determining equality, thus there should be no reassignment necessary.

```
public void SetTextBox(string newStr)
{
    //maybe this will always force TextBox events regardless of equality
    someTextBox.Text = newStr
}

public void SetTextBoxWithCheck(string)
{
    if (!someTextBox.Equals(newStr)
         someTextBox.Text = newStr;
}
```

Comment: If you set the `Text` of a `TextBox`, the property setter is going to do the check anyway. That's because it will only raise the `TextChanged` event if the value has changed. This will be true of any property that raised a changed event.

Comment: The same may be true of many properties and methods. For example, the `Stopwatch.Start` method already checks the `isRunning` field and only does work if it is `false`. Similarly, the `Stop` method only does work if `isRunning` is `true`. Note that they also test the `isRunning` field, where you would be testing the `IsRunning` property.

Comment: The compute cycles you might save by optimizing this will never, ever make a difference to UI event handling code.

Comment: See [performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) and [premature optimization](http://xkcd.com/1691/).